# how to send a data between two android app one of them is unity game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-api, speech-recognition

I am trying to make an android game (using unity game engine) and I want this game to have a speech recognition feature. 
I want to make speech recognition using android application which uses google API, but I want to send the result of recognition to another app which is the unity game.

How can I do it ? Is it valid ? 
P.S.: I know that google provides a plugin for unity but I do not want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Services.  Bounded services with a Messenger that will serve as the mediator between the remote and local process or with AIDL interface. You can also create a receiver on the remote process to receive the service obtained and a service(the sender).  Here is a good link for step by step: http://jeanmeyblum.weebly.com/scripts--tutorials/communication-between-an-android-app-and-unity

Comment: Thanks for your help, that helped me so much